# SignalR on Service Bus

Tags: azure, signalr, azureservicebus

I haven't been able to find a working sample of SignalR over Azure Service Bus.
Any pointers?
I tried Clemens' blog post, and also the readme in GitHub, but cannot make it work.
Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, having followed the example on the wiki, I have it working with the Service Bus, both in the emulator and in a live deployment. Occasionally, in the emulator, a message from SignalR to the client seems to disappear into thin air - I haven't yet figured out if this is a bug of mine or something in the Service Bus backplane - but other than this it seems to work as advertised.

Answer (score 2):

The SignalR [wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/) has a bunch of documentation on how to use SignalR. For example, how to use it with [Service Bus](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus)

Comment: I read that, but I still can't get it to work. It crashes in line GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseWindowsAzureServiceBus(connectionString, 1); with the exception "Unable to resolve the instance index of this role. Make sure Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll is deployed with your application."

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. What's not clear? Are you running in an Azure project?

Comment: Try to deploy with the most recent version of Azure SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Unable to resolve the instance index of this role" gets thrown when SignalR fails to get the RoleEnvironment data.  If you're using Azure Web Sites, this is something of a show-stopper: you can't get any role info when you don't have a role.

You can test whether this is the case by running from a web role in your local environment.